# What is the prerequisites "the same dataset" for AIC/BIC?

Tags: model-selection, aic, bic

Let make a example.

Suppose I'm doing model selection and my observation data is $Y_{N\times 1}$ and $X_{N\times K}$.(More specify, K=6)

Now I have two model, M1 and M2.

M1 includes the first three variables in X.

M2 includes the later three variables in X.

In order to selection the best model, I have to calculate the BIC for each model and compare them. In this process, I use different part of X in each model, does this still fit the prerequisites "the same dataset" for BIC?

Comment: Can you please share the source of those prerequisites you are talking about?

As I see it, you can imagine that each of your models takes the whole (X, Y) dataset but just disregards half of features. In this equivalent formulation models are learned from exactly same dataset.

Comment: The requirement is that the observations of the dependent variable (the column vector $y$) are exactly the same, not that the whole dataset (the matrix $(y|X)$) is the same.